# Android: onActivityResult will not show a layout before activating an intent

Tags: android, layout, android-intent

I have code as follows:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
   setContentView(R.layout.result);      //this is the layout I want to be displayed
   //do some stuff
   long t0,t1;
     t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
     do{
        t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
     }
     while (t1-t0<2000);                 //wait for two seconds
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);    //do the intent
}
```

What I intend to have happen, is for the layout to be shown, the app to wait on it for two seconds, and then to engage the intent. What instead happens is that the part of the code I am waiting for a result from freezes for these two seconds, then the intent runs, completely bypassing the view.

How do I get my code to function as intended?

Comment: Comment out all the lines except `setContentView(R.layout.result);` and check what happens.

Comment: Nothing changed, an answer seems to have been posted, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, create a `Handler` and use the `postDelayed()` method so you aren't freezing the `UI`

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent){
   setContentView(R.layout.result);      //this is the layout I want to be displayed
   //do some stuff

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {         
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please click the little checkmark so it may help others to find the answer easier

Comment: My code is designed to work as a sort of "scanning" utility, a user scans an item, and the result screen shows, it then goes back to scanning. The intent started is this scan, and is also the activity I get a result from.

Although the code works fine and the scan does restart after initial boot, after a second scan the app closes (no error message, no crash). Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: If it just started since you implemented this code then it is probably the `finish();` that is in there. I copied the code from something else I had and made adjustments. Try taking that out

Comment: I don't see a "finish();", it's worth noting I had to change

"public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)"

to

"public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent)"

Note the final.

EDIT: OH YOU REMOVED IT. You wily thing :P

Comment: I took the `finish()` out. If you don't have that then that isn't the problem. Thanks for the note...I have edited. If it isn't crashing and no errors, just closing, then I would guess that you have `finish()` in there somewhere. Check for that and let me know